# Same table name different schema

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-schema, database-migration

I have the following tables in my database, all with the same table name but different schema's.

- dbo.Versions
- bpm.Versions
- wf.Version
- ...

All x.Versions have a FK to the Version table.

I've created the POCO classes from it (this gave me classes like Version, Version1, .... - - I've renamed the classNames to Version and BPMVersion, .... but the mapping still exists to the right table.

This is an example of my mapping of BPMVersion that maps to bpm.Versions

```
// Primary Key
this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

// Properties
// Table & Column Mappings
this.ToTable("Version", "bpm");
this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
this.Property(t => t.VersionId).HasColumnName("VersionId");
this.Property(t => t.BPMId).HasColumnName("BPMId");

// Relationships
this.HasRequired(t => t.BPM)
    .WithMany(t => t.BPMVersions)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.BPMId);
this.HasRequired(t => t.Version)
   .WithMany(t => t.BPMVersions)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.VersionId);
```

When creating the Migration script, I've got the following exception: 
**The entity types 'BPMVersion' and 'Version' cannot share table 'Versions' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.**

I found the following blogs on the internet, it seams that EF has a problem with tables with the same name but different schema (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1641 and http://geekswithblogs.net/tonyt/archive/2013/07/02/153327.aspx )

Is there anyway to avoid this problem without renaming the table names?

Comment: mays be you can map to views...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the way EF maps table names. It looks like this is a bug in EF. As of EF 6.1, it is still in Proposed status sadly with Low priority.

See for details: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1641

**Update**: EF WorkItem 1641 noted above has been fixed on [version 6.1.2](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?Release=EF%206.1.2)

Comment: 6.1.3 has this bug

Comment: Same issue in 6.1.3. Just ran into this problem